# Old laptop with 22.04 has video issues

Tags: nvidia

loaded 22.04 into a Acer Aspire 5520 with a Nvidia 7000 video card.  The screen has vertical lines across but not as bad in favorites bar.  Many of the small windows (date) show badly.

Anything I can do for this?

Thanks
Jim

Comment: First, rule out hardware problems. Old things break in the course of time. Are you using the Live installation USB or have you installed Ubuntu to the internal hard drive? If the later, does the same thing happen if you use the Live USB and use the **Try Ubuntu** option?

Comment: In QA, I had some old video cards that had [graphic] issues with later kernels, which were noticeable on some DEsktops, but less so (*or not at all*) on others. If I wanted to use those *old* machines for myself, I'd opt for a kernel that didn't have issues (older release; eg. 20.04 using the GA kernel stack) OR use a more modern release with desktop that didn't have the issues (eg. *lighter* desktops usually).  The *Try* @user68186 suggested is appropriate to test (for 20.04 test using 20.04 or 20.04.1 media for GA, 20.04.5 will have HWE kernel stack or same kernel as 22.04)

Comment: @guiverc that is very good advice.Testing out with the older initial release (20.04) or older point release (20.04.1 or 20.04.2)  versions of Ubuntu may help find an usable kernel that is still supported.